# linear algebra bound

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a problem in course project?
I have two positive definite $n\times n$ matrices, $A$ and $B$.
I want to find the bound of singular values of a product of these matrices ?
these matrices are unknown, and I want to solve them by bound them>
So I think I have to separate them
thanks a lot.
Any suggestion or references?

Comment: Don't put multiple question marks in a row or repeat letters unnecessarily. It's not professional.

Comment: I found solution somewhere, but I'm not sure and I have not a reference

$\sigma^{1/2}_{j}(XY) \leq \sigma(\frac{X+Y}{2}) $.